# How to retrieve data from database, then pass it to Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select a column from database like so:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT start_time FROM admin_form_entry");
$start = $results[0];
```

Then, I send data to external javascript file:

```
function load_js_assets() {
if( is_page( 13 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/testrun.js');
    wp_localize_script( 'my-js', 'passedObject', array(
            'start' => $start
            )
        );
    } 
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'load_js_assets');
```

And in the Javascript file the `passedObject` is always null!

```
var start = passedObject.start;
console.log("start >>> ", start);
```

Comment: `$start` is not accessible from the `load_js_assets()` function; hence, `passedObject.start` is null. And you could fix it by moving the code which defines `$start` to inside that `is_page()` conditional.